# How accurate is this Apollo Command Module replica, and why would it be copper-colored?

Tags: apollo-program, history, space-art, museum-exhibits

Reading the Quartz article [How do you design an office for robots?](https://qz.com/1210374/how-do-you-design-an-office-for-robots/) I saw what is certainly a replica of most likely an Apollo command module ("space capsule") in several of the photos, the largest of which is shown below. It appears to have a similar sort of copper coloration as the Soyuz capsule shown in the question [Why does “Tim Peake's capsule” look like it's copper now?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21175/12102) (Don't forget to up vote the [excellent answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21176/12102) while you are there.)

Excluding the lack of a realistic door and the "aftermarket" seats inside, are there any obvious inaccuracies with the exterior? Is it quite close, or just a rough facsimile?

Also, I remember them still being white or silvery after recovery, not such a dark red color, but then again it was a while ago, and color TVs back then, well...

**Question:** How accurate is this Apollo Command Module replica, and why would it be copper-colored?

---

**below:** Photo of "the new London headquarters of XTX Markets" From [Quartz](https://qz.com/1210374/how-do-you-design-an-office-for-robots/), Stephen Bennett/Peldon Rose. Open in new window for full size.

[image: Apollo command module replica?]

Comment: This is tagged as a `space-art` question, but those with a good eye for authentic Apollo spacecraft will be well-suited for answering.

Comment: Well...the original module was 3.25m tall, and Kings Cross Building R7 has a "3.1m ceiling height (to exposed soffit)". It appears that they removed the soffit to gain some extra height. The 7th picture on https://www.architonic.com/de/project/duggan-morris-architects-r7/5105434 (with a bare office) seems to confirm that there is indeed enough room above the soffit for a few more centimeters of capsule (and the lighting). In totally other news, we have an office where humans (office workers) have been replaced with robots. It looks like a server room. No surprises there.

Comment: @Klaws that's some serious architectural and spaceflight investigating, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a replica based on the open side  to allow internal viewing which does not exist in any of the real CMs. I'm not sure if the image above has been altered to place the replica in that room however.

**below:** Cropped section of OP's image. Note after-market seating and large entrance:

[image]

Comment: I have to agree with you, and I'm surprised nobody pointed out the obvious differences before. Great work!

Answer (score 13):

The color of that replica looks about right. You're looking at the heat shield, which consists of [phenolic epoxy resin](http://www.collectspace.com/collection/artifacts_asp_heatshield.html).

[image: block of resin]

The heat shield has several outer coverings: a pore seal, a moisture barrier (a white reflective coating), and a silver Mylar thermal coating that looks like aluminum foil. These burned away during reentry, leaving the brownish resin as the outer surface.

This is the Apollo 11 CM in the [Smithsonian](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/command-module-apollo-11):

[image: CM after reentry]

[More information on the heat shield](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/CSM06_Command_Module_Overview_pp39-52.pdf).

Comment: Apparently still with factory seats. Thanks for the excellent image also, with this it's possible to do a visual comparison.

Comment: Despite the message on your Smithsonian page link "Display Status:
This object is not on display at the National Air and Space Museum. It is either on loan or in storage." I don't think it's currently sitting in the corner of that office.

Comment: The Apollo 11 CM is owned by the Smithsonian but is (or was very recently) being exhibited around the USA. It was in Houston not long ago.